# Dynamically Add Grid UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I want to add a grid and its contents on runtime. The Grid is as follows. How can I add this from Code Behind?

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="50" Margin="0,50,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Name="chkBox" MinWidth="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Name="txtBx" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Consider making a User Control to get all the benefits of XAML design, and just add/remove your control dynamically with a few lines of code instead of the many, many it would take otherwise.

Comment: I agree with the UserControl approach. And you have named controls in your xaml. Which indicates you may have binding, animation, adaptive trigger etc referencing those elements from other parts of your xaml or your code behind.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Width = 200;
grid.Height = 50;
grid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 0);
ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();
col1.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
col2.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
col3.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);
CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
cbox.MinWidth = 32;
cbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
cbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
TextBlock tblock = new TextBlock();
tblock.FontSize = 16;
tblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
tblock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
tblock.Text = "text";
TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
tbox.FontSize = 16;
tbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
tbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
grid.Children.Add(cbox);
grid.Children.Add(tblock);
grid.Children.Add(tbox);
Grid.SetColumn(cbox, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(tblock, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(tbox, 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<StackPanel Margin="0 10 0 0"  Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Name="signBoardStackPanel">                                              </StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
private void GenerateGrid()
{
    StackPanel brickStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    brickStackPanel.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1);
    brickStackPanel.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

    for (int bx = 0; bx < 8; bx++)
    {
        StackPanel rowStackPanel = new StackPanel();
        rowStackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        for (int by = 0; by < 12; by++)
        {

            Ellipse pixel = new Ellipse();
            pixel.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            pixel.Height = 4;
            pixel.Width = 4;
            //pixel.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            rowStackPanel.Children.Add(pixel);

            Rectangle pixel1 = new Rectangle();
            pixel1.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            pixel1.Height = 1;
            pixel1.Width = 1;
            rowStackPanel.Children.Add(pixel1);

        }
        brickStackPanel.Children.Add(rowStackPanel);
    }


    signBoardStackPanel.Children.Clear();
    signBoardStackPanel.Children.Add(brickStackPanel);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to assign control to columns:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Width = 200;
grid.Height = 50;
grid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 0);
ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();
col1.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
col2.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
col3.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);

CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
cbox.MinWidth = 32;
cbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
cbox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent);
TextBlock tblock = new TextBlock();
tblock.FontSize = 16;
tblock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
tblock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
tblock.Text = "text";
TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
tbox.FontSize = 16;
tbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
tbox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
grid.Children.Add(cbox);
grid.Children.Add(tblock);
grid.Children.Add(tbox);

//a different way to assign
cbox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
tblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
tbox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
```