# How can I create a Grid in UWP that changes at runtime along with a 2D array?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating a boardgame app with UWP and C#. Currently my board is defined as a 2D array that grows as the tiles are placed. I'd like to be able to have a grid that grew with the array. I also wanted the empty spaces in the grid to be defined as buttons to be able to place the tile in the grid with a click.

I tried using this method in the backend code based on an answer I saw on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052046/dynamically-add-grid-uwp) but I don't think I'm doing things the right way.

```
public Grid GridGenerator(int rows, int cols, int[,] map)
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 50, 50);
        grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Brown);
        grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition Row = new RowDefinition();
            Row.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(Row);

            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
                column.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
                if (map[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.MinHeight = 30;
                    button.MinWidth = 30;
                    button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.AliceBlue);
                    button.Name = i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                    grid.Children.Add(button);
                    Grid.SetColumn(button, j);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
                    text.Text = map[i, j].ToString();
                    text.HorizontalTextAlignment = (TextAlignment)HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    text.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    text.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    grid.Children.Add(text);
                    Grid.SetColumn(text, j);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I noticed that your method just creates a `Grid`. Do you insert the generated Grid into the UI? E.g. `this.Content = myGrid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are adding too many ColumnDefinitions through the nested loop. Try writing each step separately so that you can grasp what to do.

```
public Grid GridGenerator(int rows, int cols, int[,] map)
{
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    : 
    // 1.Prepare RowDefinitions
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        RowDefinition Row = new RowDefinition();
        Row.Height = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(Row);
    }

    // 2.Prepare ColumnDefinitions
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        ColumnDefinition column = new ColumnDefinition();
        column.Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column);
    }

    // 3.Add each item and set row and column.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (map[i, j] == 0)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                :
                grid.Children.Add(button);
                Grid.SetColumn(button, j);
                Grid.SetRow(button, i); // Set row too!
            }
            :
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

## Appendix

How to display the grid generated in code behind:To display it, you need to put it in XAML tree. For example, if you'd like to show it in another Grid (named "LayoutRoot") in XAML page,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"></Grid>
```

add it to LayoutRoot.Children in the code behind.

```
Grid board_grid = GridGenerator(5, 5, map);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(board_grid);
```

Comment: I've tried your method but the grid is still not showing. This may be a stupid question, but I've never created a grid not in xaml, do I need to declare it in the page xaml too?